# when i do "knife cookbook upload -s" i am getting the following error

Tags: chef-infra, knife

```
$ knife cookbook upload -s
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-cli-1.3.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb:226:in `parse_options': missing argument: -s (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/knife.rb:299:in `parse_options'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/knife.rb:279:in `initialize'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/knife.rb:171:in `new'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/knife.rb:171:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:123:in `run'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.6.2/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/knife:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/knife:23:in `<main>'
```

and here is the `knife.rb`:

```
log_level :info 
log_location STDOUT 
node_name 'sala' 
client_key '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/sala.pem' 
validation_client_name 'chef-validator' 
validation_key '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/chef-validator.pem' 
chef_server_url 'mychefserver.example.com:443'; 
syntax_check_cache_path '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/syntax_check_cache' 
cookbook_path '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks'
```

Answer (score 0):

from knife help page:

```
 -s, --server-url URL             Chef Server URL
```

and the error you recieved is:

```
parse_options': missing argument: -s
```

So it is evident that you are not passing the chef server URL to `-s`

have you tried `knife cookbook upload cookbook_name` ?

Comment: how to pass chef server URL to -s, here i am trying to upload the cookbooks to chef server gives me an error says temporary name resoultion now i have done knife cookbook upload -s then this error please guide me @slayedbylucifer

Comment: post your `knife.rb`. A good practice is to have the Chef-server URL configured in `knife.rb`. Also, chef has nothing do with name resolution error. This is your DNS name resolution issue.

Comment: log_level :info log_location STDOUT node_name 'sala' client_key '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/sala.pem' validation_client_name 'chef-validator' validation_key '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/chef-validator.pem' chef_server_url 'https://mychefserver.example.com:443' syntax_check_cache_path '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/syntax_check_cache' cookbook_path '/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks' @SLAYEDBYLUCIFER

Comment: Where is your `knife.rb` located? Is it really used?

Comment: your `knife.rb` looks fine and hence you do not need to use the `-s` option with knife command. Are you able to resolve `mychefserver.example.com` ? If not, then replace it with the ip address of the chef-server and check if it works.

Comment: my knife.rb is located inside /chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb oh it really used hmm i dont know.. @StephenKing

Comment: my im able to resolve like when i do ssh mychefserver.example.com from client it is going inside the machine @slayedbylucifer

Comment: Although this won't make a lot of diference, but could you replace `mychefserver.example.com:443` with `https://mychefserver.example.com` in your `knife.rb`. I have it this way in my knife.rb. Also could you run `knife cookbook upload cookbook_name` and provide the output/error you receive.

Comment: Also, as pointed out by @StephenKing, what is the location of `knife.rb` ?

Comment: my knife.rb location is /chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb @slayedbylucifer

Comment: i have change my knife.rb i replaced mychefserver.example.com:443 with https://mychefserver.example.com but still i am unable to upload my cookbooks into my server @slayedbylucifer